# Backbone.js View can't unbind events properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have some Backbone.js code that bind a click event to a button,
and I want to unbind it after clicked, the code sample as below:

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:$("#app-view"),
    initialize:function(){
        _.bindAll(this,"cancel");
    },

    events:{
        "click .button":"cancel"
    },

    cancel:function(){
        console.log("do something...");
        this.$(".button").unbind("click");
    }
});
var view = new AppView();
```

However the unbind is not working, I tried several different way and end up binding event in initialize function with jQuery but not in Backbone.events model.

Anyone know why the unbind is not working?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is that Backbonejs doesn't bind the event on the DOM Element .button itself. It delegates the event like this:

```
$(this.el).delegate('.button', 'click', yourCallback);
```

(docs: http://api.jquery.com/delegate)

You have to undelegate the event like this:

```
$(this.el).undelegate('.button', 'click');
```

(docs: http://api.jquery.com/undelegate)

So your code should look like:

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:$("#app-view"),
    initialize:function(){
        _.bindAll(this,"cancel");
    },

    events:{
        "click .button":"cancel"
    },

    cancel:function(){
        console.log("do something...");
        $(this.el).undelegate('.button', 'click');
    }
});
var view = new AppView();
```

Another (maybe better) way to solve this is to create a state attribute like `this.isCancelable` now everytime the `cancel` function is called you check if `this.isCancelable` is set to true, if yes you proceed your action and set `this.isCancelable` to false.

Another button could reactivate the cancel button by setting `this.isCancelable` to true without binding/unbinding the click event.

Answer (score 17):

You could solve this another way

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:$("#app-view"),
    initialize:function(){
        _.bindAll(this,"cancel");
    },

    events:{
        "click .button":"do"
    },

    do:_.once(function(){
        console.log("do something...");
    })
});
var view = new AppView();
```

underscore.js once function ensures that the wrapped function
can only be called once.

Comment: I like this way better than having to undelegate the event. Much simpler and cleaner, thanks for this.

Answer (score 7):

There is an even easier way, assuming you want to undelegate *all* events:

```
this.undelegateEvents();
```

Comment: Wow! i have been searching this for lot of days

Answer (score 2):

I like bradgonesurfing answer. However I came across a problem using the _.once approach when multiple instances of the View are created. Namely that _.once would restrict the function to be called only once for all objects of that type i.e. the restriction was at the class level rather than instance level.

I handled the problem this way:

```
App.Views.MyListItem = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    'click a.delete' : 'onDelete'
  },

  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this);
    this.deleteMe = _.once(this.triggerDelete);
  },

  // can only be called once
  triggerDelete: function() {
    console.log("triggerDelete");
    // do stuff
  },

  onDelete:(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.deleteMe();
  })
});
```

Hopefully this will help someone

Comment: I had a problem where my equivalent of this.triggerDelete was firing on initialize. Maybe the event model has changed in Underscore a bit since this answer. In any event, I fixed that by modifying that initialize code to: `this.deleteMe = _.once(function() {this.triggerDelete;});`

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use [*object.off*](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-off),  the code below is work for me

```
initialize:function () {

    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'mouseover', 'mouseout', 'delete', 'dropout' , 'unbind_mouseover', 'bind_mouseover');
    .......

},

events: {
    'mouseover': 'mouseover',
    'unbind_mouseover': 'unbind_mouseover',
    'bind_mouseover': 'bind_mouseover',
    .....
},

mouseover: function(){
    $(this.el).addClass('hover');
    this.$('.popout').show();
},

unbind_mouseover: function(){
    console.log('unbind_mouseover');
    $(this.el).off('mouseover');
},
bind_mouseover: function(){
    ........
},
```