# unbind events in jquery

Tags: backbone.js, event-handling, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Backbone.js View can't unbind events properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831362/backbone-js-view-cant-unbind-events-properly)

I have a div named Item with an event listener for touchend because of the swipe.js also for my indicator. Now **div#Item** has children inside now the problem is if I'm listening for touchend on **div#item** its hard to click or tap the children of **div#item**. I tried to unbind it but no luck. I am using backbone so this is my code:

```
event: {
  "touchend #item" : "CheckIndex"
},

CheckIndex : function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  var _a = this.swipe.index+1;
  $("#item).unbind('touchend');
},
```

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve here? I have used swipe.js where the swipe items have children that can be tapped? Can you pls explain what you wanna do, maybe there is another solution to ypur problem?

Comment: no actually i got it to work. the solution is within the callback function of swipe.js itself. thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

this is how i solved it.

```
CheckIndex : function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  var _a = this.swipe.index+1;
  this.$el.unbind('touchend'); //instead of $("#item").unbind('touchend');
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it a typo? You missed a closing double quotation for item

```
$("#item).unbind('touchend');
```

should be

```
$("#item").unbind('touchend');
```