# check value of $(this.el) in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm just getting started with backbone, javascript, jquery and the like.  I'm looking at a backbone view that from this post, [Backbone.js View can't unbind events properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831362/backbone-js-view-cant-unbind-events-properly), it seems like I need to undelegate my event.  My event is tied to an element with id #createBtn.  So I tried this:

```
$(this.el).undelegate('#createBtn', 'click');
```

When my backbone view gets initialized, this event gets registered with:

```
events: {
            "click #createBtn": "createNewTemplate",
```

I still see my button doing its normal thing.  I am guessing my undelegate is not working somehow and wanted a way to investigate what $(this.el) is really pointing at.  The whole JS `this` and everything is still confusing to me.  So I'm not sure if $(this.el) will even work in the method I am trying to, or if I need to be doing something else.  Any debugging hints of how $(this.el) is treated, or how I can look at that object would be super helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to remove all events or just one? `this.undelegateEvents` would remove them all (http://backbonejs.org/#View-undelegateEvents).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try console.log to output the value of this and this.el right before your undelegate. Like this...

`console.log("this is this", this)`

`console.log("this is this.el", this.el)`

Then look at the output in the console of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has some excellent debugging tools. You can step over jscript and get the contextual information. Ctrl + Shift + j. Sources. Add break point and control using step / skip buttons on the right.